# Should build a Radio app for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, streaming

I'm in the planning process of to build a iPhone app for a localRadio.
I've read alot but i'm still confused on few things:

- The radio already got a mms stream, so it would be great if i just can read this stream and play it on the iPhone. searching for a library supporting mms i've stumbled upon libmms and i'm able to read data from the mms stream. however, **I'm wondering how to playback the content in iPhone** knowing the libmms is giving me back a **char *** array of the content of the stream.
- I've read here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH1-DontLinkElementID_29 that any app submitted to the app store that need to play long running audio/video should use Live HTTP stream..

Does this mean i can't use MMS????

thanks for the help.

-

Answer (score 0):

It *should* do this, but I don't think that means it *must* do it.

I don't believe Apps like Pandora use Live HTTP streaming.

Comment: In fact i've understood that it require this for certains type of streaming app: video mostly and if you download more than 10Mb video in the app....

Comment: Do you have an idea of how i can playback the audio read from a mms stream?